# PHP & file_get_contents() leading in failing HTTP request!

Tags: php, parsing

i wrote a php-script which is loading the xml/html of a given url, parses it and writes it to an database. Since some hours ago I'm getting the strange mentioned error, not all the times but definitely too much.

Do you have any suggestions as to what is going wrong?

Here are the lines of code which are supposed to cause the logged error:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$data = file_get_contents($item->get_link());
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($data);
```

Comment: *What* error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Which one is failing, the XML library, or the file_get_contents? Is the remote site up? Does it return the data you are expecting it to? Is the data a valid DOM document?

Comment: One option is that the site you're scraping doesn't like repeated hits and is throttling/blocking you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the site which is called is supposed to be always online, I  really don't think that't the mistake. Also it worked very well the last week and even month, can't get why they should start throtteling me right now. But thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's not much to work off, so here's some possible issues:

1) `$item->get_link()` is not returning a valid URL

2) You assume `file_get_contents` will always get the data. What happens when there's a network issue? The server is down? You need to make sure `$data` is valid before doing something with it.

```
$data = file_get_contents($item->get_link());
```

3) `$data` is not parse-able by the dom parser, possibly for one of the previous reasons.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
```

Comment: Mhm, I'll check that and will be back soon. Thanks!